# how to terminate a python2.7 process after executing the desired function while killing that process using linux kill command

Tags: python-2.7

I want to execute a desired function before killing a python2.7 process through the Linux kill command from a bash script. How is it possible?

I tried atexit module, but it is not helpful from the outside the python.

Or Is there any shutdown hook in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `signal` module to trap the `TERM` signal that `kill` sends:

```
import signal, os

def handleSigTERM(*args):
    print "OMG I'M GETTING KILLED"
    # Do what you want

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handleSigTERM)

print "I'm process:", os.getpid()
while True:
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Jose. It gives the exact solution for my request.